# How to group duplicated JSON Objects in JOLT Schema or NiFi Processors?

Tags: json, grouping, apache-nifi, dml, jolt

How can i convert INPUT below into the following OUTPUT ? 
I've tried using EvaluateJSONPath -> MergeContent, but not getting the right result.

Can anyone help and share screen-captures/codes please ?

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nthv.png)

```js
{"Customers":{
 "AccountProfile": {
        "full-name": "applicant A",
        "mobile-number" : "8435739739",
        "email-id" : "A@gmail.com"
    },
 "AccountRegistration": {
        "ID No." : "11111111111",
        "ID Type" : "HKID"
 }
   }
 }{"Customers":{
 "AccountProfile":{
        "full-name": "applicant A",
        "mobile-number" : "8435739739",
        "email-id" : "A@gmail.com"
    },
 "Contact":{
  "Phone No": {
        "Residential Phone" : "77777777",
        "Home Phone" : "88888888"
         }}
}
}
```

[Expected OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxYnF.png)

```js
{"Customers":{
 "AccountProfile": {
        "full-name": "applicant A",
        "mobile-number" : "8435739739",
        "email-id" : "A@gmail.com"
    },
 "AccountRegistration": {
        "ID No." : "11111111111",
        "ID Type" : "HKID"
 }
, "Contact":{
  "Phone No": {
        "Residential Phone" : "77777777",
        "Home Phone" : "88888888"
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: post your code youve tried so far, and for the input and output paste them as text into the question not as images

Comment: hi can anyone help please ?